# Spinner dialog background color

Tags: android, android-spinner

I know this question will be a duplicate but , even after going through many suggestions, I still couldn't change the dropdown style for popup diolouge of a spinner.

Below is my Spinner xml -

```
 <Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dialog"
    android:popupBackground="#ff0000"
    android:entries="@array/State_list"/>
```

You see, I already made popup background color as `ff0000` and its still not reflecting so please dont give this as suggestion but if you see any other way, please do let me know here, Many thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try `spinner.setBackgroundColor();`

Comment: Thanks for the response, yes i tried as     
    `code` s.setPopupBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spinner_bg));`code`

and my spinner_bg as below - 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#3a5264" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#142f44" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>

Comment: And its still not working